# MYSQL Limiting left join query

Tags: mysql, left-join, sql-order-by, limit

I have a query which uses a few left joins to bring back data. The dilemma is that i want to `LIMIT` and also `ORDER BY` the results from one of the left joins and thus limiting the total numbers of rows brought back.

The table i am trying to order and limit is `table4`

**My query:**

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS e.meta_1, a.requestid, b.clientid, c.job_description, d.forename
FROM quotations_request AS a 

 LEFT JOIN table1 AS b ON (a.assigned_to = b.userid) 
 LEFT JOIN table2 AS c ON (a.job_costing = c.jobid) 
 LEFT JOIN table3 AS d ON (a.clientid = d.clientid) 
 LEFT JOIN table4 AS e ON (e.quotationid = a.requestid)

 WHERE a.archived = '0' AND (e.meta_1 = LCASE('requested') )
```

**What i have tried:**

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS statuss.meta_1, a.requestid, b.clientid, c.job_description, d.forename,
 FROM quotations_request AS a 

 LEFT JOIN table1 AS b ON (a.assigned_to = b.userid) 
 LEFT JOIN table2 AS c ON (a.job_costing = c.jobid) 
 LEFT JOIN table3 AS d ON (a.clientid = d.clientid) 
 LEFT JOIN (Select meta_1 from table4 where quotationid = a.requestid ORDER BY uploaded_date DESC LIMIT 0, 1) 
 as statuss ON (statuss.quotationid = a.requestid)

 WHERE a.archived = '0' AND (statuss.meta_1 = LCASE('requested') )
```

**The result:**

After trying the above I got an error saying `a.requestid` is unkown in the where clause ( for the last left join)

Comment: And using `LIMIT` in the subquery seems reasonable...so what happened next?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, i should have added (updated question) i then ended up with the error saying "a.requestid" is unkown field. remember a.requestid is from the main table on the second line

Comment: The dilemma described in your first paragraph has nothing to do with the error which is preventing your query from running. Given the predicate based on e.meta_l in your first query, the LEFT JOINs are a very inefficient redundancy and should be inner joins.

Comment: Note that LEFT JOIN e... WHERE e is the same as INNER JOIN e. Also, it's unusual to use a case sensitive collation. Just sayin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS statuss.meta_1, a.requestid, b.clientid, c.job_description, d.forename
 FROM quotations_request AS a 

 LEFT JOIN table1 AS b ON (a.assigned_to = b.userid) 
 LEFT JOIN table2 AS c ON (a.job_costing = c.jobid) 
 LEFT JOIN table3 AS d ON (a.clientid = d.clientid) 
 LEFT JOIN (
    select *
    from (select
            t.*,
            @rn := if(quotationid = @qid, @rn + 1, 
                if(@qid := quotationid, 1, 1)
            ) rn
        from (
        select *
        from table4
        order by quotationid, uploaded_date desc) t cross join (
            select @rn := 0, @qid := -1
        ) t2
    ) t where rn = 1
) 
 as statuss ON (statuss.quotationid = a.requestid)

 WHERE a.archived = '0' AND (statuss.meta_1 = LCASE('requested') )
```

The user variables @rn and @qid are used to find the top 1 row from table4 with latest uploaded_date and then join it with the other tables

Comment: I get an SQL error telling me to check manual on 'from webmanage_uploads
        order by quotationid, uploaded_date desc) t cros'

Comment: this is the code i pasted from your answer (with modified field names which are relevant for me) , does it look correct? https://codeshare.io/anzz7n

Comment: i can't access the above site. I've updated my answer. can you try that? there was a missing `*` in the subquery

Comment: one day can i become like you?

Comment: @jimmyturner Premature deification is as bad as premature optimisation ;-)

Comment: After me, are we? :D

Comment: Hey - you're a god. I can't touch that. ;-) However, having the CROSS JOIN outside the scope of the ORDER BY cannot work in the way that you think it does. It *may* return the correct answer, but it cannot be guaranteed. That said, it may well be the right approach - just a minor flaw in its execution.